# how to support large screen size with API level 17?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have two layout types `layout-v17` and `layout-large`. I want to know which one will be chosen if I have a device that is large and also greater than API level 17?

Other question is should I design my drawables again for `xlarge` screen size? I know `mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi` etc but for example, in `mdpi` resolution my image view size is **100x100** but in `xlarge` size I should set it as **400x400**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **Layout-large** will work for large devices. It doesn't matter what is the API level.

For you second question well If you can your images through different **dimen** files then you can take that approach else you can check the following folders for different resolution.

```
res/values/dimens.xml(default)
    res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml   (240x320 and nearer resolution)
    res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml   (320x480 and nearer resolution)
    res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml   (480x800, 540x960 and nearer resolution)
    res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280 - Samsung S3, Micromax Canvas HD, etc) 
    res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml (1080x1920 - Samsung S4, HTC one, etc)
    res/values-large/dimens.xml  (480x800)

    res/values-large-mdpi/dimens.xml (600x1024)
    res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml  (600x1024)
    res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml  (800x1280)
    res/values-xlarge-xhdpi/dimens.xml (2560x1600 - Nexus 10")
    res/values-large-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (1200x1920 - Nexus 7"(latest))
```

Comment: so what i should do for different level APIs.

Comment: delete those folders only value folders for different level works as we define theme of app in that or drawable-v21 is useful because if you want to add some special effect like ripple, reveal etc. Rest no need of different api level folders for image sake.